# How to escape string programmatically in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, escaping

I would like to

1. escape string programmatically, so that it can be used inside quotes in Kotlin/Java code
2. know, if some escape codes were used

For example, string

in code:

> ```
> "abc\"d\""
> ```

if printed:

> ```
> abc"d"
> ```

should be converted to

in code:

> ```
> "abc\\\"d\\\""
> ```

if printed:

> ```
> abc\"d\"
> ```

Comment: Do you also want to do this for unicode sequences (e.g. `\u0009`) or only for the "standard" escape sequences `\t`, `\b`, `\n`, `\r`, `\'`, `\"`, `\\ ` and `\$`?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you're using IntelliJ idea, you can copy a string like `abc"d"` to the clipboard, and paste it inside the `""` quotes in a Kotlin file, and the IDE will paste `abc\"d\"` in there for you.

Comment: Secondly, in Kotlin, you can use [triple-quoted strings](https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans/Introduction/Triple-quoted%20strings/Task.kt) so you don't have to worry about escaping them and how they would print.

Comment: Thirdly, if you're targeting the JVM, you can use [Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String)).